# How can I toggle a class on click with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to toggle an active class on click to change CSS properties.

My code is below. Can anyone advise how I should do this? Without creating a new component for each item is it possible to do this?

```
class Test extends Component(){

    constructor(props) {
  
    super(props);
    this.addActiveClass= this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
  
  }
  
  addActiveClass() {
    
    //not sure what to do here
    
  }

    render() {
    <div>
      <div onClick={this.addActiveClass}>
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div onClick={this.addActiveClass}>
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
        <div onClick={this.addActiveClass}>
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  }

}
```

Answer (score 111):

Use state. See the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addActiveClass= this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            active: false,
        };
    }
    toggleClass() {
        const currentState = this.state.active;
        this.setState({ active: !currentState });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div 
                className={this.state.active ? 'your_className': null} 
                onClick={this.toggleClass} 
            >
                <p>{this.props.text}</p>
            </div>
        )
  }
}

class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent text={'1'} />
                <MyComponent text={'2'} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without creating an extra component?

Comment: You want to break apart complex components into smaller components see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components

Comment: I have broken the component up, but this still adds `active` to each element on click. I only want one element to have an active class

Comment: This cannot be called toggled 'active' class because other elements's active classes are still there.

Comment: can you please update the answer to use `onClick` as opposed to all lowercase as you have incorrectly

Answer (score 76):

You can also do this with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook).

```
function MyComponent (props) {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggleClass = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <div 
      className={isActive ? 'your_className': null} 
      onClick={toggleClass} 
    >
      <p>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 30):

I would prefer using the `&&` operator in an inline `if` statement. In my opinion it gives cleaner codebase this way.

Generally you could be doing something like this:

```
render(){
return(
  <div>
    <button className={this.state.active && 'active'}
      onClick={ () => this.setState({active: !this.state.active}) }>Click me</button>
  </div>
)
}
```

Just keep in mind that arrow functions are and ES6 feature and remember to set `this.state.active` value in the class constructor.

```
this.state = { active: false }
```

Or if you want to inject CSS in JSX you are able to do it this way:

```
<button style={this.state.active && style.button} >button</button>
```

And you can declare style json variable:

```
const style = { button: { background:'red' } }
```

Remember to use camelCase on JSX stylesheets.

Answer (score 16):

Well, your addActiveClass needs to know what was clicked. Something like this could work (notice that I've added the information which divs are active as a state array, and that onClick now passes the information what was clicked as a parameter after which the state is accordingly updated - there are certainly smarter ways to do it, but you get the idea).

```
class Test extends Component(){

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeClasses: [false, false, false]};
    this.addActiveClass= this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
  }

  addActiveClass(index) {
    const activeClasses = [...this.state.activeClasses.slice(0, index), !this.state.activeClasses[index], this.state.activeClasses.slice(index + 1)].flat();
    this.setState({activeClasses});
  }

  render() {
    const activeClasses = this.state.activeClasses.slice();
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={activeClasses[0]? "active" : "inactive"} onClick={() => this.addActiveClass(0)}>
          <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div className={activeClasses[1]? "active" : "inactive"} onClick={() => this.addActiveClass(1)}>
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
          <div  onClick={() => this.addActiveClass(2)}>
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**You can simply access the element classList which received the click event using event.target then by using toggle method on the classList object to add or remove the intended class**

```
<div onClick={({target}) => target.classList.toggle('active')}>
  ....
  ....
  ....
</div>
```

Equevelent

```
<div onClick={e=> e.target.classList.toggle('active')}>
  ....
  ....
  ....
</div>
```

OR by declaring a function that handle the click and does extra work

```
function handleClick(el){
    .... Do more stuff
    el.classList.toggle('active');

}
<div onClick={({target})=> handleClick(target)}>
  ....
  ....
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28337422)

Answer (score 6):

React has a concept of components state, so if you want to switch it, do a `setState`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.addActiveClass= this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    isActive: false
  }
}

addActiveClass() {
  this.setState({
    isActive: true
  })
}
```

In your component use `this.state.isActive` to render what you need.

This gets more complicated when you want to set state in component#1 and use it in component#2. Just dig more into react unidirectional data flow and possibly redux that will help you handle it.

Comment: I understand `state` but this still doesnt really explain how to update the classname when an element is clicked

Comment: in your jsx markup do - `<div className={this.state.isActive ? 'active' : ''}>`. It's about conditional rendering, but still relies on state.

Comment: but that will add the active class to each item on click. I just want the item clicked on to have the `active` class name

Comment: why each item? It'll add the class to the item you add the condition for. Ideally your items should be abstracted to the `Item` component. You'll then include it 3 times and will basically have 3 items, each having its own `isActive` state. Is it what you mean?

Comment: without splitting it out into an `Item` component is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is not a good way to do it without having an Item component, hence my answer and what @dhorelik is now telling you. It's really the best way to go.

Comment: well, let's say you can keep not just `isActive` in state, but the item name (1, 2, 3). This way in your items you can base the condition on that: `<div className={this.state.currentItem === 1 ? 'active' : ''}>`. And do the same for 2 & 3

Comment: @dhorelik i have seen you can use `e.target.className` -- this gets me some bit of the way but its not possible to remove the older ones that were set

Answer (score 5):

using React you can add toggle class to any id/element, try

**style.css**

```
.hide-text{
    display: none !important;
    /* transition: 2s all ease-in 0.9s; */
  }
.left-menu-main-link{
    transition: all ease-in 0.4s;
}
.leftbar-open{
    width: 240px;
    min-width: 240px;
    /* transition: all ease-in 0.4s; */
}
.leftbar-close{
    width: 88px;
    min-width:88px;
    transition: all ease-in 0.4s;
}
```

**fileName.js**

```
......
    ToggleMenu=()=>{
             this.setState({
                isActive: !this.state.isActive
              })
              console.log(this.state.isActive)
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div className={this.state.isActive===true ? "left-panel leftbar-open" : "left-panel leftbar-close"} id="leftPanel">
                    <div className="top-logo-container"  onClick={this.ToggleMenu}>
                            <span className={this.state.isActive===true ? "left-menu-main-link hide-from-menu" : "hide-text"}>Welcome!</span>
                    </div>

                    <div className="welcome-member">
                        <span className={this.state.isActive===true ? "left-menu-main-link hide-from-menu" : "hide-text"}>Welcome<br/>SDO Rizwan</span>
                    </div>
    )
    }
......
```

Comment: I'd like to add to this that you can use the following code-style if you have a static class that you don't want to define for each of the "isActive" statements: `className={\`left-panel ${this.state.isActive===true ? 'leftbar-open' : 'leftbar-close'}\`}`

Answer (score 2):

The above answers will work, but just in case you want a different approach, try classname: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Answer (score 2):

[A good sample](https://codepen.io/focuswish/pen/RoOXWG) would help to understand things better:

**HTML**

```
<div id="root">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box.green {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

**React code**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {addClass: false}
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({addClass: !this.state.addClass});
  }
  render() {
    let boxClass = ["box"];
    if(this.state.addClass) {
      boxClass.push('green');
    }
    return(
        <div className={boxClass.join(' ')} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>{this.state.addClass ? "Remove a class" : "Add a class (click the box)"}<br />Read the tutorial <a href="http://www.automationfuel.com" target="_blank">here</a>.</div>       
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add **toggle class** or toggle state on click

```
class Test extends Component(){
  state={
  active:false, 
 }
  toggleClass() {
    console.log(this.state.active)
    this.setState=({
     active:true,
   })
  }

    render() {
    <div>
      <div onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this)}>
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @cssko for providing the correct answer, but if you tried it yourself you will realise it does not work. A suggestion has been made by @Matei Radu, but was rejected by @cssko, so the code remains unrunnable (it will throw error 'Cannot read property bind of undefined'). Below is the working correct answer:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addActiveClass = this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    };
  }
  addActiveClass() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({
      active: !currentState
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = {
        this.state.active ? 'your_className' : null
      }
      onClick = {
        this.addActiveClass
      } >
      <
      p > {
        this.props.text
      } < /p> < /
      div >
    )
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      MyComponent text = {
        'Clicking this will toggle the opacity through css class'
      }
      /> < /
      div >
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.your_className {
  opacity: 0.3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

React has a concept of components state, so if you want to Toggle, use setState:

> 1. App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import TestState from './components/TestState';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>React State Example</h1>
        <TestState/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

> 2. components/TestState.js

```
import React from 'react';

class TestState extends React.Component
{

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            message: 'Please subscribe',
            status: "Subscribe"
        }
    }

    changeMessage()
    {
        if (this.state.status === 'Subscribe')
        {
            this.setState({message : 'Thank You For Scubscribing.', status: 'Unsubscribe'})
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({ message: 'Please subscribe', status: 'Subscribe' })
        }
    }
    
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
        <button onClick={()=> this.changeMessage() } >{this.state.status}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TestState;
```

> 3. Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I started learning React recently and wanted to build a tab just to see how far my knowledge has gone. I came across this and decided to implement something without redux. I kind of feel the answers don't reflect what op wants to achieve. He wants only one active component but the answers here will set all components active. I have given it a shot.

Below is a tab file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Tab extends Component {

    render(){
        const tabClassName = "col-xs-3 tab-bar";
        const activeTab = this.props.activeKey === this.props.keyNumber ? "active-tab" : null;
        return (
                <div 
                    className = {`${tabClassName} ${activeTab}`}
                    onClick={()=>this.props.onClick(this.props.keyNumber)}
                >
                    I am here
                </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Tab;
```

The tabs file...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tab from './tab';

class Tabs extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentActiveKey: 0,
            tabNumber: 2
        };

        this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this);
        this.setTabNumber = this.setTabNumber.bind(this);
    }

    setTabNumber(number){
        this.setState({
            tabNumber: number
        });
    }

    setActive (key){
        this.setState({
            currentActiveKey: key 
        });
    }

    render(){
        let tabs = [];
        for(let i = 0; i <= this.state.tabNumber; i++){
            let tab = <Tab key={i} keyNumber={i} onClick={this.setActive} activeKey={this.state.currentActiveKey}/>;
            tabs.push(tab);
        }
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {tabs}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Tabs;
```

your index file...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tabs from './components/tabs';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Tabs />
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

and the css

```
.tab-bar {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.active-tab {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

This is a skeleton of something I want to improve on so increasing the tabNumber beyond 4 will break the css.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code I came Up with:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import './header.css'

export default class Header extends Component{
    state = {
        active : false
    };


    toggleMenuSwitch = () => {
        this.setState((state)=>{
            return{
                active: !state.active
            }
        })
    };
    render() {
        //destructuring
        const {active} = this.state;

        let className = 'toggle__sidebar';

        if(active){
            className += ' active';
        }

        return(
            <header className="header">
                <div className="header__wrapper">
                    <div className="header__cell header__cell--logo opened">
                        <a href="#" className="logo">
                            <img src="https://www.nrgcrm.olezzek.id.lv/images/logo.svg" alt=""/>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" className={className}
                           onClick={ this.toggleMenuSwitch }
                           data-toggle="sidebar">
                            <i></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="header__cell">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my approach. Using hooks and context provider.

**Nav.js**

```
function NavBar() {
  const filterDispatch = useDispatchFilter()
  const {filter} = useStateFilter()
  const activeRef = useRef(null)
  const completeRef = useRef(null)
  const cancelRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let activeClass = '';
    let completeClass = '';
    let cancelClass = '';
    if(filter === ACTIVE_ORDERS){
      activeClass='is-active'
    }else if ( filter === COMPLETE_ORDERS ){
      completeClass='is-active'
    }else if(filter === CANCEL_ORDERS ) {
      cancelClass='is-active'
    }
    activeRef.current.className = activeClass
    completeRef.current.className = completeClass
    cancelRef.current.className = cancelClass
  }, [filter])

  return (
    <div className="tabs is-centered">
      <ul>
        <li ref={activeRef}>
          <button
            className="button-base"
            onClick={() => filterDispatch({type: 'FILTER_ACTIVE'})}
          >
            Active
          </button>
        </li>

        <li ref={completeRef}>
          <button
            className="button-base"
            onClick={() => filterDispatch({type: 'FILTER_COMPLETE'})}
          >
            Complete
          </button>
        </li>
        <li ref={cancelRef}>
          <button
            className={'button-base'}
            onClick={() => filterDispatch({type: 'FILTER_CANCEL'})}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

**filterContext.js**

```
export const ACTIVE_ORDERS = [
  "pending",
  "assigned",
  "pickup",
  "warning",
  "arrived",
]
export const COMPLETE_ORDERS = ["complete"]
export const CANCEL_ORDERS = ["cancel"]

const FilterStateContext = createContext()
const FilterDispatchContext = createContext()

export const FilterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(FilterReducer, { filter: ACTIVE_ORDERS })
  return (
    <FilterStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <FilterDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </FilterDispatchContext.Provider>
    </FilterStateContext.Provider>
  )
}
export const useStateFilter = () => {
  const context = useContext(FilterStateContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("place useStateMap within FilterProvider")
  }
  return context
}
export const useDispatchFilter = () => {
  const context = useContext(FilterDispatchContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("place useDispatchMap within FilterProvider")
  }
  return context
}


export const FilterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FILTER_ACTIVE":
      return {
        ...state,
        filter: ACTIVE_ORDERS,
      }
    case "FILTER_COMPLETE":
      return {
        ...state,
        filter: COMPLETE_ORDERS,
      }
    case "FILTER_CANCEL":
      return {
        ...state,
        filter: CANCEL_ORDERS,
      }
  }
  return state
}
```

Works fast, and replaces redux.

Answer (score 0):

```
const aDiv = useRef(null);

function app(){
const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState();
useEffect(()=>{
if(isDark){
 aDiv.current.classList.add('dark-mode')
}else{
 aDiv.current.classList.remove('dark-mode')
}

},[isDark]}
return <div className = "app" ref = {aDiv}> </div>
```

useRef to id the element to toggle the class, then a boolean useState to track switching, on true, we get the ref's current classList then add a className else we remove the className.
All this happen in the useEffect with our useState as dependency array.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    // ️ toggle isActive state on click
    setIsActive((current) => !current);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button className={isActive ? "bg-salmon" : ""} onClick={handleClick}>
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click a button and set the state to disabled, later do whatever you need based on operation in the function.

Button:

```
<button className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm' onClick={(e) => { fn(e, 123) }}>do fn</button>
```

Function:

```
const fn = async (e, id) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.target.className = 'btn btn-sm btn-light disabled'
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: There are already a lot of answers to this question, please make sure to highlight what your answer adds to question that has not been said before.

Comment: It's simply works without all the refs/states