# React toggle active class on click of anchor using Gatsby Js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, gatsby

I am Using GatsbyJs and am trying to accomplish a active class toggle. I have a simple Component composed of a anchor tag with a span inside. I want to change some css by toggling a active class on the anchor **when it is clicked**. Here is my code so far, I am also using styled-components. I tried some vanilla js in the broken code section below, that obviously didn't work hence broken code.

Thanks in advance

styles

```
const Menu = styled.a`
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer; padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
  span, span:before, span:after{
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  }
  span:before{
    top: -10px; 
  }
  span:after{
    bottom: -10px; 
  }
  .active span{
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .active span:before, .active span:after{
    top:0;
  }
  .active span:before{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .active span:after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
`
```

component

```
const TemplateWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <Wrapper>
      <Menu id="nav-toggle" className="menu"><span></span></Menu>
      {children()}
    </Wrapper>       
  </div>
)

TemplateWrapper.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func,
}

export default TemplateWrapper
```

broken code

```
document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" )
  .addEventListener( "click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle( "active" );
  });
```

This is the html that is rendered

```
<a class="menu sc-bwzfXH SqHLW" id="nav-toggle"><span></span></a>
```

Comment: Can you post the react code where `#nav-toggle` gets rendered ?

Comment: Ok I added what is rendered above. Also I fixed something in the menu component it was missing the nav-toggle id. However the broken code section doesn't even allow the app to run. If I delete it the app runs and everythingrenders fine.

Comment: I see the problem, you need to add "&" before ".active span" in your styled component. like &.active span ...

Comment: And what's the error that you get?

Comment: @m0rjjj the site completely crashes when I include the broken just, so the css part is working however I haven't tested add the active class manually so you might be partly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you can take a look here [REACT - toggle class onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/react-toggle-class-onclick/42630780)
. There are several answers that show the way how you can achieve that, but things get messier when you want to use more than one class.

I like this package to handle the cases where you deal with styling with multiple classes based on the props or state: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames.

I simplified the styles for the sake of clarity of this answer and assumed that the `menu` is a global class, you want to apply as well.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Wrapper = styled.div``;

const Menu = styled.a`
  span {
    color: green;
  }
  &.active span {
    color: blue;
  }
`;

class TemplateWrapper extends Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ isActive: !state.isActive }));
  };

  render() {
    const menuClass = classNames({
      menu: true,
      active: this.state.isActive
    });

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Menu id="nav-toggle" className={menuClass} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <span>Test</span>
        </Menu>
        {this.props.children}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

TemplateWrapper.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};

TemplateWrapper.defaultProps = {
  children: null
};

export default TemplateWrapper;
```

Notice the ampersand (&) before `.active`. As stated in the [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#supported-css), `styled components` supports all of CSS plus nesting.

> Ampersands (&) get replaced by our generated, unique classname for that styled component, making it easy to have complex logic.

However, you can achieve the same effect without `classnames` by fully utilizing [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) functionality. Take a look at this [section](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) of the documentation.

A few changes needed:

```
const Menu = styled.a`
  span {
    color: ${props => (props.active ? 'blue' : 'green')};
  }
`;
```

The render method would look like that:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Menu id="nav-toggle" className="menu" active={this.state.isActive} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <span>Test</span>
      </Menu>
      {this.props.children}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error `Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `TemplateWrapper`, expected a ReactNode.`

Comment: That's weird, as stated in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), node refers to "Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array (or fragment) containing these types.". So it's the right prop for the `children`. What `children` have you supplied? more specifically <TemplateWrapper>what do you have here?</TemplateWrapper> :D

Comment: hmm, I don't have a `<TemplateWrapper>stuff goes here</TemplateWrapper>` anywhere. I tried adding just a `<TemplateWrapper/>` on it's own, but I get the same error. I have added exactly what I have in my code in my above answer in the update section.

Comment: I am using Gatsby js and this is my `layout/index.js` file so I am not using <TemplateWrapper> anywhere. Hope we can figure this out.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the `children` is supposed to be where my pages render. I have a `layout/index.js` file which is my code above and then I have a `pages/index.js, pages/portfolio.js` and they each respectively render inside of the `children` section just wondering if this is Gatsby js related.

Comment: Oh, that explains a lot, I changed the prop type, because I wasn't aware of you using this as a Gatsby layout. Just use `children: PropTypes.func` and `{this.props.children()}` as you had it initially.

Comment: Ok were almost there, that fixed the issue everything loads, however when I click the `<Menu>` anchor component no active class is added or removed, how is the click bound to the `<Menu>` component. So Close!

Comment: Never mind that, I was missing `active =` and `onClick` thanks so much.

Comment: Great! You can update your question, since the `Failed prop type` error was strictly related to Gatsby. You can even delete the code you added in the update, so the question stays clearer, maybe it will help someone else one day :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use component `state` to mange this.
Code will look like:

**Updated:** Moved logic to `Menu` component as it makes more sense to place it there. Below working example

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.menuClick = this.menuClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      menuClass: '',
    }
  }
  
  menuClick(e) {
    const menuClass = this.state.menuClass === '' ? 'active' : '';
    this.setState({ menuClass });
  }
  
  render() {
    const {children, id} = this.props;
    const menuClassName = `menu sc-bwzfXH SqHLW nav-toggle ${this.state.menuClass}`;
    
    return (<a className={menuClassName} id={id} onClick={this.menuClick}>{children}</a>);

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Menu><span>Test link</span></Menu>,  document.getElementById('menu'))
```

```css
.menu {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: blue;
 }
 
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon as I get back to my PC.

Comment: How do I integrate this with my current components? I am already exporting my template wrapper do I export twice o am confused.

Comment: You should modify `Menu` component not `TemplateWrapper `  to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Can I not use styled components this way, I am setting that like this `const Menu = styled.a' color:blue';` How would I do this is styled-components?