# Reactjs : How I can change button style when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd, ant-design-pro

I am new to ReactJS, Currently I am using `ant.design` for my interface and In `ant.design` I am using [Switch Steps](https://ant.design/components/steps/#header) for Wizard form. I want to change Next Button style when clicked . I am new to this platform please guide me

Thanks

Comment: may be your question is same like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/react-toggle-class-onclick

Comment: ON the docs page you linked to there is an another example (https://ant.design/components/steps/#components-steps-demo-step-next) that does exactly that!

Comment: @JesperWe exactly but I want to change just button

Comment: You mean the user clicks next, and the button updates but the Steps do not advance?

Comment: @JesperWe I mean to say When User click on next button, the button state is changed to loading button and proceed to next step . I want to change button state

Comment: @awaiskhan  I mean to say When User click on next button, the button state is changed to loading button and proceed to next step . I want to change button state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to change the loading state you can modify the example in the docs to be:

```
import { Steps, Button, message } from 'antd';

const Step = Steps.Step;

const steps = [{
  title: 'First',
  content: 'First-content',
}, {
  title: 'Second',
  content: 'Second-content',
}, {
  title: 'Last',
  content: 'Last-content',
}];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: 0,
      loading: false
    };
  }

  next() {
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current, loading: true });
  }

  prev() {
    const current = this.state.current - 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  render() {
    const { current, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Steps current={current}>
          {steps.map(item => <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />)}
        </Steps>
        <div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div>
        <div className="steps-action">
          {
            current < steps.length - 1
            && <Button type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={() => this.next()}>Next</Button>
          }
          {
            current === steps.length - 1
            && <Button type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={() => message.success('Processing complete!')}>Done</Button>
          }
          {
            current > 0
            && (
            <Button loading={loading} style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will cause the button to go into loading state when Next is clicked. However you need some external event that is fed into the component to tell it when to remove the loading state.

This can be done by having a `this.prop` that is changed from the parent component and detected in `componentWillReceiveProps`, where you do `this.setState({loading:false})`, or by making `next()` call some asynch method which resets the loading state in its callback.