# Setting the style of an element after a click doesn't work in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this Navbar element which holds my links like this:

```
<li id="navbar-about-li">
  <Link className="navbar-a" to="/about" onClick={this.onUpdate.bind(this)}>
    About me
  </Link>
</li>

<li id="navbar-projects-li">
    <Link className="navbar-a" to="/projects" onClick={this.onUpdate.bind(this)}>
        Projects
    </Link>
</li>
```

When I click one of the buttons, the button gets a underline, but it doesn't remove he underline from all the other buttons. Here's the onUpdate function:

```
    onUpdate(e) {
        this.removeAllStyling();
        this.setUnderLineForElement(e.target);
    }
```

And here's the removeAllStyling function:

```
removeAllStyling() {
        //remove the underline from all li tag elements
        let links = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (let link of links) {
            link.style.textDecoration = "none";
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried printing the links in removeAllStyling and they're the correct elements that I want, so I know that isn't the problem here...

Comment: Don't use raw javascript to set the underline of elements like that. Let react style the elements itself.

Comment: Hmh okay I tried `link.style = noUnderline;` where noUnderline is just a object with `textDecoration: "none",`, but for some reason I now have 2 elements underlined.. So that kinda worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REACT - toggle class onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/react-toggle-class-onclick)

Comment: You're using React, but you're fighting the framework by doing DOM manipulation manually. It'll lead to bugs and undefined behaviours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set underline on `e.target` and it isn't a `li`, `e.target` reference to `<Link />`

Try this:

```
removeAllStyling() {
  const links = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-a");

  for (const link of links) {
    link.style.textDecoration = "none";
  }
}
```

And you should not use `DOM API` using React. In this case you should use state of react component like this (for example):

```
onUpdate(e) {
    this.setState({
        activeLink: e.currentTarget.dataset.number,
    });
}
```

And if you use react-router-dom there are  component with `activeClassName` props: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

And one more: of course you should bind your handlers into constructor because `.bind` returns NEW function every time and your `<Link>` will re-render every time too.

Comment: NavLink is exactly what I was looking for! Also can you explain your last sentence a bit more?

Comment: @randomboiguyhere of course. When you call the `.bind` it returns new function. You call `.bind` every time the `render` is called. When you update local state (for example) the `render` is called and your `<Link>` gets new props because `.bind` returns new function and `<Link>` re-render too although this is not necessary. You should bind all your handlers once in `constructor`