# React js button color change not staying

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react js project where I want to change the color of a button when it is clicked. I can successfully change the color of the button when clicked, but say I clicked my mouse somewhere else on the screen, the switched color does not stay.

[image]

**index.css**

```
.btn {
    background-color:var(--dark);
    border-color: var(--white);
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: var(--white);
    font-family: "Roboto Mono",sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    border-radius:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
.btn--dark:focus{
    color: var(--dark);
    border-color: var(--white);
    background-color:var(--white)
}
```

Is `focus` not the right way to do this?
Once I have clicked a button, how can I keep it's new color and make sure it does not disappear once I have clicked something other than the button.

Comment: If you want to use some CSS/HTML hackery it's possible, but in general you'd need JS for this

Comment: :focus is for when it has focus, like on hover or somehow using keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do what you want with CSS alone - you must write some JS to add and remove a class name with each click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REACT - toggle class onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/react-toggle-class-onclick)

Comment: Yeah I thought js would be needed. What would be the main idea of how to create this?

Comment: Can you post some of your js code, ideally need to see how/where the buttons are being rendered. And can you have more than one option selected?

Comment: None of the solutions given seemed to work. I went with a totally different approach but the result is as intented. It's much to large of a change to post as an answer, I say closing the question is a good choice. (maybe need's debugging details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using some state.
It would be like

```
<Button color="my_color" > Click me! </Button>
```

You can put code inside the prop "color" and in your function of the button only change any state.
I think this solution it will be.

```
    const [color, setColor] = useState(false);
    

    return (

     <Button
       onClick={ () => setColor(!color) } 
       color={ color ? 'blue' : 'red'} 
     > 
      Click me! 
     </Button>
    
    )
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Question, would the second code go in my Button component? And the first code go in my app.js

Comment: This would only really work if you have 1 button on the page, or if you made your own button component. Since there is 3 on the page you would have to do something different. Though state is still the answer