# Get activate Nav-Item in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, sidebar, reactstrap

I'm looking for a sidebar of [reactraps](https://codesandbox.io/s/5ku6t). I wanna change the background colour of the Nav-item when I click on it
I try to use activeClassName but it's not working :(

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

[image]

Comment: I would toggle a CSS class on-click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/react-toggle-class-onclick

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<NavLink to="/faq" className={`${window.location.pathname === '/faq' ? "selected" : "null"}`}>
      FAQs
    </NavLink>
```

Comment: It's not working sir :(

Comment: change  this.props.location.path to window.location.pathname

Comment: Not working too