# how can i make a radio button using React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm not sure how I can build a selection button, like to a radio button in React using TypeScript. The button must have an image and a color change of the button when selected.

Here is an example photo

[image]

I created a component, but I don't know how I can make the selection.

````
interface ItemProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  options: Array<{
    label: string;
    value: string;
    image: string;
  }>;
}

const Selector: React.FC<ItemProps> = ({
  label,
  name,
  options,
  ...rest
}: ItemProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col">
        <p>{label}</p>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <>
            <label className="btn" htmlFor={name}>
              <input type="radio" id={name} value={option.value} />
              <img src={option.image} />
              <span className="checkmark"></span>
              <p>{option.label}</p>
            </label>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};```
````

Comment: hi, perhaps add an active class on selection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/react-toggle-class-onclick

Comment: Have a parent element hold the selected state of the form and pass that state to the child. From there the child can use ternary to determine which class to actively use based on the state of the parent component.

Comment: You can actually handle this selection with state and state and a dynamic class to highlight the selected option.