# Change **child element** className with parent onClick

Tags: reactjs

Given component code

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    //<--how to change the button className to toggleUp
  };
  return (
    <div
      onClick={handleClick}
      style={{ padding: "6px", backgroundColor: "steelblue" }}
    >
      <button className="toggleDown"> button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and styles.css as follows

```
.toggleDown {
  background-color: blue;
}

.toggleUp {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Please see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-haslett-d7cg53)

How should I be able to change the button className when in `handleClick` for div?

P/S: this is not duplicate on [REACT - toggle class onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/react-toggle-class-onclick) since that post is about changing div className in my context, not button className.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from putting `className={isActive ? 'your_className': null}` on the button - it really doesn't matter whether the parent is a `<div>` or a `<button>`

Comment: do you mean isActive as a state variable @CertainPerformance?