# how to change button background color onclick and unclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

how to background button color change onclick and unclick

i tried to change the button color on onclick and unclick but not work

```
<button
                    id={`instruction-button`}
                    data-id="instruction-button"
                    data-testid="instruction-button"
                    className={`instruction-button ${
                        transparent ? 'transparent' : ''
                    }`}
                    aria-label={'Activity instructions'}
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    label="Activity instructions"
                >
                    <i className={`r180 instructions ${playing ? 'playing' : ''}`} />
                </button>

instructionsButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '8px',
        top: '8px',
        zIndex: '10',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        transition: 'transform 0.3s ease',
        '& .instruction-button': {
            position: 'relative',
            display: 'inline-block',
            width: '24px',
            height: '24px',
            outline: 'none',
            textAlign: 'center',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            transition: 'transform 0.3s ease',
            background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
            boxShadow: '0 0 0 4px #fff',
            backgroundClip: 'padding-box',
            borderRadius: '12px',
            '& i': {
                color: theme.colors.softBlack,
                background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
                borderRadius: '12px',
                fontSize: '24px'
            },
            '& i.playing': {
                color: 'red'
            }
        },
```

const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);`

```
const handleClick = async e => {
        if (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

        if (disabled === true) {
            if (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return false;
        }

        if (playing) {
            AudioPlayer2.stop(audioReference);
            setPlaying(false);
            if (typeof onSoundEnd === 'function') {
                onSoundEnd();
            }
            reduxStore.dispatch(uiSlice.actions.setCaptionSrc(''));
        } else {
            AudioPlayer2.stopAll();
            if (typeof onSoundStart === 'function') {
                onSoundStart();
            }
            if (audioReference === '') {
                if (typeof onSoundEnd === 'function') {
                    onSoundEnd();
                }
                return;
            }
            reduxStore.dispatch(
                uiSlice.actions.pauseAnimations(BTN_CLICK.INSTRUCTION)
            );

            await AudioPlayer2.playSync(audioReference);
            setPlaying(false);

            if (
                reduxStore.getState().ui.pauseBtnClick === BTN_CLICK.INSTRUCTION
            ) {
                reduxStore.dispatch(uiSlice.actions.unpauseAnimations());
            }

            if (typeof onSoundEnd === 'function') {
                onSoundEnd();
            }
        }
    };
```

i tried to change the button color on onclick and unclick but not work

anyone help on this  how to change button color onclick and unclick

Comment: How do you unclick a button? Do you mean something like a checkbox? repeating your question 4 times in other word do not add clarity. What do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: Still, what do you mean by unclicking a button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I toggle a class on click with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630473/how-can-i-toggle-a-class-on-click-with-react)

Comment: *not work* turns me off in helping, sorry. Though one thing I can see is you don't actually set setPlaying(true); anywhere

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up local state to be either `true` or `false`.
2. Set up a handler to toggle the state between `true` and `false`.
3. Using state determine what the background colour should be. Here I've used a [conditional/ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) in the `className` attribute to switch between a blue and red class.

The implementation details of this may differ from your use-case because you may be using CSS modules or styled components, for example, but it will generally follow this pattern.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Button() {

  // Initialise local state
  const [ clicked, setClicked ] = useState(false);

  // Toggle the state between true/false
  function handleClick() {
    setClicked(prev => !prev);
  }

  // Use a conditional operator to choose what
  // colour to render based on the state
  return (
    <button
      className={clicked ? 'red' : 'blue'}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >Click me
    </button>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Button />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```